# capturing values from multiple groups of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, forms

I think this one is simple but I really need some help. Thanks to anyone who helps!!

I'm trying to capture the input from two sets of radio buttons. The first group works but the second one does not.

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<p>Please select one from each group.</p>

<form action="#">

    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="classic">classic type<br>
      <input type="radio" name="type" value="modern">modern type<br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="typeface()" value="Review type selection">
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="type" size="50">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
      <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout1">layout1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout2">layout2<br>
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="layout()" value="Review layout selection">
      <br><br>
      <input type="text" id="layout" size="50">   
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**JS (before `</body>`)**

```
function typeface(){
  var type = document.forms[0].type;
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i=0;i<type.length;i++){
    if (type[i].checked){
      txt = txt + type[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("type").value = "You selected: " + txt;
}

function layout(){
  var layout = document.forms[0].layout;
  var txt = "";
  var i;
  for (i=0;i<layout.length;i++){
    if (layout[i].checked){
      txt = txt + layout[i].value + " ";
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("layout").value = "You selected: " + txt;
}
```

Comment: @roko if possible could you help me a little more? I'm so new to this! I'd like to take the results of the radio buttons selections and put them together and add .jpg so I can match it to a .jpg file. For example, if the results was "classic" and "layout1" I want to match it to "classiclayout1.jpg"

Comment: You can ask a new question! Use the accepted answer code with what you tried to make it work. I'd be glad to hop in.

Comment: Probably you need something like: http://jsbin.com/gumiy/5/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about not pissing off the users by confirming their radio selection, but do something like:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gumiy/3/edit)**

HTML

```
<form id="myForm" action="#">

  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="classic">classic type<br>
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="modern">modern type<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="type" size="50">
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout1">layout1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" value="layout2">layout2<br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="layout" size="50">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

JS:

```
function getId(id){ return document.getElementById(id); }
function writeVal(){
  getId(this.name).value = "You selected: "+this.value;
}

var radio = getId('myForm').querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
for(var i=0; i<radio.length; i++) radio[i].onchange = writeVal;
```

The above will work immediately in radio `change` and show the selected text value in the `text` field.

Comment: Thank you. I really like this!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know exactly why but if you change the layout function name to something else it works
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HsP4D/)

```
<input type="button" onclick="layout2()" value="Review layout selection">

function layout2()
{
...
}
```